# Making an app using ssh to shutdown macbook

Tags: macos, ssh

I have been trying to create an app that can shutdown my mac using ssh. I've tried `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh./id_rsa.pub ssh "my computer" | sudo shutdown -h now` but I get an error message saying `zsh:exit 1` and `zsh: suspended (tty output) sudo shutdown -h now` and I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your command:

`ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh./id_rsa.pub ssh "my computer" | sudo shutdown -h now`

1. That's two commands. You need a semicolon or line break to separate them
2. `ssh-copy-id` needs the private key, but you've provided the public key
3. That key looks like it has an extra dot in the key path
4. You're running `sudo shutdown -h now` *locally* rather than remotely

Run this just one time. It will prompt you for your user's password on `mycomputer`:

```bash
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa mycomputer
```

Then you can run this:

```bash
ssh -t mycomputer "sudo shutdown -h now"
```

This will be interactive since you need to enter your user password for `sudo`, but at least the key prevents you from needing to enter it a second time to gain access to the system.

You could reduce this by allowing your user to run that command without a password. From a shell on that computer (`ssh mycomputer`), run `visudo` (if the last line of that file looks like `@includedir /etc/sudoers.d`, quit and run something like `visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/local`) and add this to the end:

```
gjwlsdnd224  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown -h now
```

where `gjwlsdnd224` is your username. If you do this, you don't need `-t` passed to `ssh`.